# Spring security - Why can't I access static resources as defined in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm refactoring an Spring-Boot application and I've run into

```
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/rootProject/css/app.css]
```

for all CSS and JavaScript files.

The project is structured like so:

- rootProject

  - src

    - main

      - java
      - resources

        - css
        - js

My main security implementation is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { 

    // other methods

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO: api must be protected but default alpaca connector does not support protected sources. We'll need to register a custom connector
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/images/**",
                        "/css/**",
                        "/health/**",
                        "/js/**",
                        "/api/**",
                        "/reports/**",
                        "/h2-console/**",
                        "/oauth/authorize",
                        "/oauth/confirm_access",
                        "/oauth/token_key").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority(BaseRoleEnum.BASE_ADMIN.toString())
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .and()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .sameOrigin()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
    }
}
```

And my main configuration class is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "basePackages")
// Enable caching for the application
//@EnableCaching
public class TouchConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    // other beans and methods

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }
}
```

What am I missing here so this works as intended?

Comment: Why `.addResourceLocations("/static/");` There is no such folder in the project structure you provided. also `/rootProject/css/app.css` Is it exact message or you replaced `rootProject` part? And what are your html css/js links? Something like this? `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/main.css">` because thats what you are saying in `.addResourceLocations("/static/");` but error shows different link

Comment: Exact message is: `WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/central/css/app.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'`

Comment: and folder structure is it correct? do you have `resources/static/css` or just `resources/css`?

Comment: Yes, `resources/static/css`.

Comment: Try `registry.addResourceHandler("/central/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");`

Answer (score 1):

I have added all the static resource path security as none. Which is a global config. Below example is in XML.. you should be able to do the same in config also.

```
<!-- Global Security Ignore for resources -->
    <security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" ></security:http>
    <security:http pattern="/*.css*" security="none" ></security:http>
    <security:http pattern="/*.js*" security="none" ></security:http>
    <security:http pattern="/*.gif*" security="none" ></security:http>
    <security:http pattern="/*.png*" security="none" ></security:http>
    <security:http pattern="/*.jpg*" security="none" ></security:http>
    <security:http pattern="/*.svg*" security="none" ></security:http>
    <security:http pattern="/*.ico*" security="none" ></security:http>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should have .css and .js files under /resourses/static/** path
[project static resources structure in elipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcRsb.png)

also,make sure that you right the link in the right way <href="resources/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

Comment: I have it so! The structure is `/main/resources/static/**`. It's the same structure as your image.

Comment: how adout tring to ignore the request to these resources like this   @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
        webSecurity.ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/css/**")
        .antMatchers("/js/**")
        .antMatchers("/font/**");
    }

Comment: also,make sure that you right the link in the right way <link href="resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

Comment: I'm using thymeleaf, so my links look like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/static/css/app.css}"/>`

Comment: i think you can try this i work fine with me @Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/");
}

Comment: Actually, it has something to do with Thymeleaf's implementation. I'm still trying to figure out what's happening.